# Parser NULL (DTEParseMgd) error when trying to set up SSIS package job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

Whenever I try to set up a SQL Server Integration Services Package job (through the SSIS Catalog within SSMS), I get the error

> Parser NULL (DTEParseMgd).

The version of the SQL server is "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3210089) - 13.0.4202.2 (X64)   Dec 13 2016 05:22:44"

Here is a screenshot of that message:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkuIg.png)

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fixed this by installing the latest CU update.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found an in-depth answer [here](https://michelleadavid.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/parser-null-dteparsemgd/):

> The Visual Studio was at a higher version then the SQL Server Management Studio.

So the fix is to update SSMS to match the Visual Studio version.

Comment: However if anyone has an alternative that does not involve updating, as I am unable to update SSMS on the server I am using due to administrative privileges.